# plot data with small differences

Tags: plotting

I want to plot data with very small differences. I can't see the differences in my plot:

[image]

Comment: Please post *code*, not (just) images. And take a look at `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {4.60001, 4.60002, 4.60003, 4.60004}

ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Your definition of `AxesOrigin` was the evildoer

Answer (score 1):

Your Data are plotting just fine;

```
sdata = {4.67884, 4.67874, 4.67862, 4.67850, 4.67843, 4.67845, 4.67856, 4.67872, 4.67885};
```

Compare the two plots p1 and p2;

```
p1 = ListLinePlot[sdata, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}];
p2 = ListLinePlot[sdata, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}, AxesOrigin -> Automatic];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

You simply messing with `AxesOrigin`

I suspect the help Files `Axes Origin` and `Axis` will support you;

> AxesOrigin is an option for graphics functions that specifies where
> any axes drawn should cross.
>
> Axis  is a symbol that represents the axis for purposes of alignment
> and positioning.

Comment: That's a duplicate of my answer given hours ago :)