# ListPlot of data with small differences

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

This following is a similar question as [plot data with small differences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/plot-data-with-small-differences), but I am not able to solve my problem with the proposed solutions.

```
list = {1.00000012, 1.00000012, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000015};
```

All of the commands produce the same non-scaled plot:

```
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All]
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> Full]
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

All commands above produce the same non-scaled plot:

[image]

Comment: Your syntax is just a bit off. The `PlotRange` specs has to be `PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}`, where one or both `{min,max}` can be `Automatic`. So you can do `ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {Min[list], Max[list]}}]`

Comment: Or, if you're using 10.1 and higher, use `MinMax`, e.g. `PlotRange -> {Automatic, MinMax[list]}`.

Comment: `Standardize` is useful here I think.

Comment: @chuy: how would you solve this with `Standardize`, that looks promising.

Comment: `ListPlot[Standardize[list], PlotRange-> All,Frame-> True, Axes-> False, Filling-> Axis]` is one possible way.  The y-axis now represents how many standard deviations a point is away from the mean.

Comment: @chuy: but the vertical axis is wrong ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the solution provided by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87818/18476):

```
list = {1.00000012, 1.00000012, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000015};

ListPlot[list, "AllowMicroRanges" -> True]
```

[image: Plot]

To get useful yticks, one can use for example

```
ListPlot[list, "AllowMicroRanges" -> True, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, N[FindDivisions[{#1, #2}, 7], 10] &}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Great ... the 5th point is only wrong ... to be honest the documentation of mathematica is sometimes very short, incomplete and this undocumented functions, methods, etc. are annoying ... I would like to know from Wolfram what the strategy behind that is?

Comment: Yes it works excellent without any additional adjustments  (v. 10.4.1).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach that essentially sidesteps whatever problem ListPlot seems to have in creating an appropriate plot range and ticks. Instead of plotting the values themselves, it may be more useful to plot the differences between the values and the minimum to highlight a trend. The rest of the code is just there to create some reasonably readable ticks, expressed in "parts per billion difference" on the vertical axis:

```
ListPlot[
 list - Min[list],
 PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]},
 PlotRange -> {{0.5, 5.5}, Automatic},
 PlotRangePadding -> {None, Scaled[0.1]},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None,
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["difference / ppb", Black, 16]},
 FrameTicks ->
  {Automatic,
   Function[{min, max},
    With[{vals = Subdivide[0, Round[max, 1*^-8], 6]},
     Transpose@
      {vals, Rationalize[1*^9 vals, 0]}
    ]
   ]
  },
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12]
]
```

[image: final plot]

As an aside, this is an example of the kind of gymnastics that are sometimes necessary to produce a decent-looking plot in MMA, and a strong case for the use of e.g. [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), which makes some of these adjustments quite a bit more flexible.

Comment: You can simplify the task by plotting `10^9 (list - Min[list])`

Comment: @BobHanlon Very true. When that first didn't occur to me, I decided to muck with the ticks, and developed tunnel vision... Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MarcoB: This is sometimes of advantage what you propose to plot the differences. I was in general interested why `ListPlot` has no method to do it on its own (see the `AllowMicroRanges` Option in the solution of Karsten 7. who got it from Mr.Wizard).

Answer (score 3):

I'll propose `ListLogPlot` because;

```
list = {1.00000012, 1.00000012, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000015}
```

> {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

```
myList = SetPrecision[list, 9]
```

> {1.00000012, 1.00000012, 1.00000013, 1.00000014, 1.00000015}

```
ListLogPlot[{myList}, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
PlotMarkers -> Style["⦿", Large, Red]]
```

[image]

As an alternative you can use [ScalingFunctions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html)

```
ListPlot[myList, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This helps ... it is strange why for the linear scaling plot there seems not to be a solution which sets the best vertical plot range.